# Can two fields that have monomorphism to each other not be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

More precisely, let $F_1, F_2$ be fields, and we have none zero homomorphisms $f: F_1 \to F_2$ and $g: F_2 \to F_1$ (actually both are monomorphism since $F_1, F_2$ are fields), is there a possibility that $F_1$ is not isomorphic to $F_2$?

Comment: Equivalently, a tower $M/L/K$ with $M\cong K$ but $L$ not isomorphic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate on the example given by [perpetuallyconfused](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/570087/perpetuallyconfused), indeed $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C(x)$ provide a counterexample.

Some additional elements.

$\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed: this is well known. $\mathbb C(x)$ is not. In particular the polynomial $p(t) = t^2-x \in \mathbb C(x)[t]$ can't have a root $\frac{r(x)}{s(x)} \in \mathbb C(x)$. If it was the case, you would have $r^2(x)=x s^2(x)$ with the contradiction that the left polynomial of the equality is having an even degree and the right one an odd one. Therefore $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C(x)$ are not isomomorphic.

Also, the identity is an obvious embedding $\mathbb C \hookrightarrow \mathbb C(x)$.

Regarding an embedding $\mathbb C(x) \hookrightarrow \mathbb C$, you have to know that [Two algebraically closed fields are isomorphic if and only if they have the same transcendence degree over their prime fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3623568/two-algebraically-closed-fields-are-isomorphic-if-and-only-if-they-have-the-same) (proof provided in the link). And also that the cardinality of the [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) of an infinite field $F$ has the cardinality of $F$. As the cardinality of $\mathbb C(x)$ is the one of $\mathbb C$, the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb C(x)}$ of $\mathbb C(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ and therefore you can embed $\mathbb C(x)$ into $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 3):

So apparently, [it is possible for this to fail](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/theme-and-variations-schroeder-bernstein/), though I don't profess to understand the counterexamples given in the comments. You are asking if fields satisfy the [Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_property), and it appears that they do not.

Edit: I take that back, I think I understand one example, if not its construction. There is a natural inclusion $\mathbb{C} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}(x)$ and a (complicated) inclusion $\mathbb{C}(x) \hookrightarrow F$ where $F \cong \mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$. However, the complex field is algebraically closed whereas $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is (apparently) not, so they cannot be isomorphic.