# Can a Field lie "strictly" inside itself?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Is there a field $F$ and a non-zero ring homomorphism $f:F \rightarrow F$ such that $f$ is not surjective?

In other words, is it possible for a field to strictly lie inside itself? I couldn't come up with an example, but I don't see this couldn't be the case. Clearly this is impossible for finite fields and for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Consider $t \longmapsto t^p$ for $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, or any morphism $x \longmapsto R(x)$ of $k(x)$ where $R$ is a rational fraction which isn’t the quotient of two polynomials of degree at most one.

Comment: You could also consider $F = k(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ with $x_1 \mapsto x_2, x_2 \mapsto x_3, \ldots$.

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia article [perfect field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field) helpful to find fields which are not perfect.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That should be an answer, it's certainly the simplest construction I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with an arbitrary field $k$, and let $F=k(x)$ be the field of rational functions in one variable $x$ over $k$. There is a homomorphism $f:k(x)\to k(x)$ that acts on any rational function by substituting $x^2$ for $x$ (leaving the coefficients unchanged). It's clearly a non-zero homomorphism, and $x$ is not in its range.

Comment: This would have been my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$ are both algebraically closed fields, and have transcendence degree $2^{\aleph_0}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{C} \simeq \overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$ [(see here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3623568/two-algebraically-closed-fields-are-isomorphic-if-and-only-if-they-have-the-same), but the inclusion is not surjective.